# API to get all instagram stories for a user?

Tags: android, json, instagram

I need to get all Instagram stories for an account. From which Instagram API can I get this?

for this api no more registrations are allowed 
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token="+USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

Kindly let me know the complete steps to get the Instagram stories JSON.

Answer (score 0):

api ، لا يُسمح بالتسجيلات " https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/؟access_token= " + USER_ACCESS_TOKEN